# Ansible: UNREACHABLE: ssh: connect to host port 5986: Connection refused

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I run then command

```sh
ansible windows -m win_ping
```

I have this error

```json
192.168.0.161 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.161 port 5986: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true
```

My hosts file is

```ini
[windows]
192.168.0.161

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=PET-OPD
ansible_ssh_password=lemonade``
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

I want to connect from Linux Control Node to Windows Remote Node and
I've tried to add some commands and I didn't get anything.

Comment: As the error messages states, you can not connect via SSH to WinRM (HTTPS/SOAP).

Comment: why i can not connect?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you can not connect via SSH to [WinRM (HTTPS/SOAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal) and which is a kind configuration error only.

You may have a look into the Ansible documentation of [Windows Remote Management](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_winrm.html) and use the there given examples like

```yaml
---
- hosts: windows
  become: no
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    ansible_user: username@MY.EXAMPLE.COM
    ansible_password: Password
    ansible_port: 5985
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Can I use SSH to authenticate to Windows hosts?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_faq.html#can-i-use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate-to-windows-hosts)
- [Can I connect to Windows hosts over SSH?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_faq.html#can-i-connect-to-windows-hosts-over-ssh)